# Why doesn't Bootstrap Card contain image?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the current **Bootstrap** Card from their [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/drum-kit-min.png">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4>Card title</h4>
    <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when adding my image it overflows the card container like so:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried changing the size of the image but to no avail:

```
.card-img-to {
  width: 10px;
}
```

I also have tried adding the bootstrap `image-responsive` class to it. Is there any way to get this image responsive to the card, or do I have to photoshop the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving `max-width:100%;` to img

```
.card img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

or add `img-responsive` class to img tag

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="yourpath/img.jpg" />
```

Comment: Img-Responsive didn't work for me but the other one did! Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class is incorrect. You are using `.card-img-top` in the HTML, and `.card-img-to` in your stylesheet. You'll need to add the missing `t`. Since you are controlling the width of the parent `.card`, you can set the image to `width:100%`.

```css
.card {
  width: 250px; /* Using this as an example, you can keep 20rem */
  overflow: hidden; /* Optional */
}
.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4>Card title</h4>
    <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your HTML code

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/drum-kit-min.png" style="width:100%" alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Or you can put the image as background of **.card**

**CSS**

```
.card {
    background-image: url("img/drum-kit-min.png");
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
     <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```